# Patch tests in issue queues?

Tags: community-official-site

How does one get a patch tested in core and attached to an issue queue (with the pretty red or green styling)?

Is it automatically done when you attach a patch? Or do you have to have an account to the qa.drupal.org server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patches uploaded on issues are automatically tested if they meet the right conditions which include:

- not excluded based on name (described in description on upload field)
- project has testing active
- patch is again d6-8 banch

For core, testing is enabled; if you upload a patch against Drupal 7, for example, it will automatically be tested. For other projects, it can be enabled if you are a maintainer by looking at the *Issue* settings tab; there is a checkbox to enable testing.

For more information, see [Automated testing](https://www.drupal.org/node/332678).